# Whats the best way to make smooth waterslide type tracks?

Tags: mesh

**Im creating game inspired by Wipeout games everything is good except, im relatively new to blender and was researching past two days for a way to create tracks like in wipeout fusion, super smoothly rotated  and all that good stuff i have tried:**

1. Making a curve bevel it make a track then make curve into the mesh didnt worked because imported into unity these meshes didnt had empty space inside them aka ship was stuck instead of falling on the mesh AND it was a full circle i didnt need that
2. Make a straight cubes then use deform and bend these cubes and connect into one track, literally impossible to work with takes hours and couldnt connect bended cubes together perfectly
3. again, make cube then bend with shift + W, didnt worked either because endings were rotated as well no matter what i did cause of that track was full of obvious connections due to bumps weird stretches etc.
4. Ask for solutions in various discord groups noone answered what could help.

**I hope someone knows a way how can i make these tracks, thanks.**

Comment: how could one add (Road) texture in way that they tile properly, I tried doing this but didn't get proper results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bezier circle. Go into the curve properties, and increase the *Extrude* property.

[image]

Go into edit mode, select all the control points with <kbd>A</kbd> and set the tilt to 90°. (Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the right hand panel if it is closed)

[image]

Tweak the tilt of each control point to have some kind of curvature.

[image]

Add a solidify and edge split modifier to get depth.

[image]

Select two control points and richt click > Subdivide to add a new one between the two. Tweak them, tilt them to your liking.

[image]

Adjust the resolution units to keep the poly count low

[image]

If you want a custom profile, add a bezier curve

[image]

And use it as your bevel object

[image]

Result : 676 verts

[image]

Comment: Thanks helped me alot easy to work with, everything smooth as well really good stuff, but i have one problem, couldnt really do a loop like rotating 360 around and keep going any blender magic to help me make that?

Comment: how could one add (Road) texture in way that they tile properly, I tried doing this but didn't get proper results

Comment: @Flubby check the texture space panel in the curves properties. Otherwise please ask a new question referencing this one and make sure to add as much detail as possible regarding your setup. Cheers